# Dynamically allocated list of dynamically allocated structs is overwriting

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

In the following code, I can't figure out for the life of me why I get the same output (ie the same name) when running the dump_data() method after adding 2 (or more) User_struct (with different names) using the addUser() method.

```
struct Friends_struct {
    struct User_struct *this;
    struct Friends_struct *next;
};

typedef struct Friends_struct *Friends;    

typedef struct User_struct {
    const char *name;
    Friends amigos;
} User;

static User **userList;             // global table of users
static int numUsers;                // global number of users
static int tableSize;               // global size of table


void create_amigonet() {    
    tableSize = INIT_TABLE_SIZE;
    numUsers = 0;

    userList = malloc(tableSize * sizeof(User *));
}

void addUser(const char *name) {
    userList[numUsers] = malloc(sizeof(User));
    userList[numUsers]->name = name;
    userList[numUsers]->amigos = 0;

    numUsers++;

    if (numUsers == tableSize) {
        tableSize += INIT_TABLE_SIZE;

        User **moreUsers;
        moreUsers = realloc(userList, tableSize * sizeof(User *));
        userList = moreUsers;
    }
}

void dump_data() {
    for (int i=0; i<numUsers; i++) {
        printf("%s; friends:", userList[i]->name);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Different .c file:

```
void do_add(const char *name) {
    addUser(name);
}

int main(void) {
    create_amigonet();
    do_add("Dan");
    do_add("Jim");
    dump_data();
}
```

If this is run, the output I expect would be something like

```
Dan; friends:
Jim; friends:
```

yet I am getting

```
Jim; friends:
Jim; friends:
```

How/where am I overwriting my data?

Comment: Doesn't compile. When I fix the compile errors it works as expected. `userList[numUsers]->amigos = 0;` is wrong. amigos is a `Friends` struct you cant assign it a value of 0. Also dumpData or dump_data?

Comment: 1) `userList[numUsers]->amigos = 0;` --> `userList[numUsers]->amigos = (Friends){0};` 2) `void dump_data() {` -->  `void dumpData() {` then [DEMO](http://ideone.com/lDSs6j)

Comment: perhaps, using the input from the console  unlike a posted code.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I was trying to post a full example.  The main() referenced above is actually in a different .c file.

Comment: Example code update for better understanding.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing only a `char` pointer in `User_struct` and the pointers you pass in the `addUser` calls are only temporaries. You should change the type of `name` to a `char` array of sufficient length and use `strcpy` to copy the name within `addUser`.

I cannot fully explain why the example is actually showing the error because I thought that both name strings should be valid throughout `main()` but it seems that the generated code is reusing the location where "Dan" was stored and therefore you are getting "Jim" twice after the second `addUser` call.

Comment: Yes under different circumstances the code would blow up when the name strings went out of scope. Here it will survive as the strings "Dan" and "Jim" would end up in the data segment and be valid for the lifetime of the application.